# 400 ERROR: Invalid URI when uploading new PyPI package (twine)

Tags: python, pypi, twine

I followed the official documentation for uploading packages to PyPI, as well as the information provided in PyPI readme, but I get a HTTP 400 error each time:

```
$ twine upload dist/*
Uploading distributions to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/ 
Enter your username: bradaallen
Enter your password:
Uploading brad_nlp_helpers-0.1.1-py3-none-any.whl
HTTPError: 400 Client Error: home_page: Invalid URI for url: 
https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
```

I am using a ~/.pypirc

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
  pypi
  pypitest

[pypi]
username=bradaallen
password=[password]

[pypitest]
username=bradaallen
password=[password]
```

For packages, I am using `twine version 1.9.1 (pkginfo: 1.4.1, requests: 2.12.4, setuptools: 27.2.0, requests-toolbelt: 0.8.0, tqdm: 4.14.0)`

When I use `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel upload` I get the same issue:

```
Submitting dist\brad_nlp_helpers-0.1.1.tar.gz to
https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/ Upload failed (400): home_page: Invalid URI
error: Upload failed (400): home_page: Invalid URI
```

I have not specified the repository, as that is recommendation that is given by the API when uploading. I am seeing a `404 error` at the link that PyPI recommends and am not seeing an alternative site I should use!

This is my first package, and I am not seeing this error elsewhere on the internet. Any thoughts re: what's going on?

Comment: I just visited the page https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/ and got error 404 (not exists). What version of `twine` do you use? May be you need to create `.pypirc`?…

Comment: Hi @phd - thanks for your comment. I've updated the version of twine and .pypirc data I used. I also noticed the website does not exist - it is the URL recommended by the PyPI API. I am not seeing this problem elsewhere, which makes me wonder if it is a recent issue with PyPI. Thoughts?

Comment: No idea. I created `.pypirc` 15 years ago and have been happily using `python setup.py upload` ever after. :-)))

Comment: @phd :) - I get the same issue with `python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel upload`. I just ran that code and got this error:                                                       
`Submitting dist\brad_nlp_helpers-0.1.1.tar.gz to https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/
Upload failed (400): home_page: Invalid URI
error: Upload failed (400): home_page: Invalid URI`

Comment: You don't have `https://upload.pypi.org/legacy/` in .pypirc, do you?! PS. I switched to twine a year ago, no problems so far.

Comment: @phd: I don't! I updated my post to reflect the .pypirc I am using. I can add a line to the .pypirc stating `repository = www.correcturl.com`, but I don't know what that URL should be. Have you used twine in recent days? I'm curious if it is a global problem with the documentation or if it is something that is affecting me specifically. I appreciate your quick and consistent responses!

Comment: I use https://pypi.python.org/pypi . No, I didn't use use twine for a few months.

Answer (score 3):

Amazing. I also posted this as an Issue on [Twine's GitHub page](https://github.com/pypa/twine/issues/258).

It turns out the URL in the `setup.py` file should correspond to where the code is being hosted (which makes sense). I had put my personal website as the URL and I guess the unit tests at Warehouse were rejecting me... it's now uploaded.

Thank you again @phd!

Answer (score 1):

When you run `$ twine upload dist/*` it means you are redeploying all versions of the package available in project directory. Your error shows that previous version **0.0.1** already exists in your pypi.org account. It shouldn't be redeployed unless deleted from your pypi.org account.

Solution:

Always specify the version your latest wheel generated after modifying your package code by running

`$ twine upload dist/<your-latest-whl-version>`

Comment: Have been doing it wrong for years. Thank you for this answer!

Answer (score 0):

Just a few minutes ago tried to upload a package and got this problem. :-) To fix: upgrade `pip`, `setuptools` and `twine` to the very latest versions:

```
pip install -U pip setuptools twine
```

Remove or comment out repository from `~/.pypirc`:

```
[distutils]
index-servers =
    pypi

[pypi]
#repository: 
username: …
```

`twine upload` now works!

Comment: Hi @phd - Thanks so much for continuing to help with this! :) When I run `pip install -U pip setuptools twine` on both my Mac and Win7 machines, I get this error: `OSError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/bradaallen/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools-27.2.0-py2.7.egg'` I *do not* get this error if I upgrade the 3 packages separately - but I am also told that each package is "up-to-date" and I get the same errors as in my original post. Thoughts?

Comment: Search `*.pth` files in `/Users/bradaallen/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/` and remove (comment out) mentioning of `setu‌​ptools-27.2.0-py2.7.‌​egg`. setu‌​ptools 27 is a bit old now.

Answer (score 0):

check your setup.py file

put url =""

build again

check
"""
PKG-INFO inside the src//PKG-INFO

"""
Home-page: 
if it is there go on deploy

thanks

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

If you have such a setting, try removing it from your setup.py file:

```
url='home_link'
```

This method helped me

Answer (score -3):

When you use README.md file as long_description in the setup.py, some strings such as ".*" do not support in PyPI. So, there is a need to remove them and rebuild the WHL file and upload it again by twine.

Comment: Your answer is a little unclear.  What do you mean by *who file uploaded*?  And might you be more specific about *some characters*?  If you could [edit] your answer to clarify the English a little and include an example of a `README.md` that caused the problem, it would make this answer a lot more useful, thanks.